# Office-UI-Fabric-react uncheck checbox

Tags: office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript, office-ui-fabric-react

How Can I uncheck a checkbox dynamically from the code?

I need to uncheck some checkboxes at the same time from the code when I press a button.

I'm using:

SharePoint Framework - Typescript - Office UI Fabric - React

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabio,

I'm assuming that you're using Office UI Fabric Checkbox and DefaultButton
for this answer -- let me know if you aren't.

To solve this issue use the following steps:

1. Make sure to add a state variable to your state definition. Example:

   ```
   export interface IExampleState {
     isChecked: boolean;
   }
   ```
2. Initialize your state in your constructor to a default value

   ```
   constructor(props: IExampleProps) {
       super(props);
   (this);
       this.state = {
         isChecked: false
       };
     }
   ```
3. Bind the **checked** attribute of your checkbox to your state. For example:

   > <Checkbox
   >       **checked={this.state.isChecked}**
   >   label="Standard checkbox"
   >   onChange={ this._onControlledCheckboxChange }
   >   />
4. Create an **onClick** event handler for your button that will change the state.

   ```
   private _buttonClicked(): void {
     this.setState({ isChecked: true });
   }
   ```
5. Bind the **_buttonClicked** event handler in your constructor:

   constructor(props: IExampleProps) {
         super(props);
         **this._buttonClicked = this._buttonClicked.bind(this);**
         this.state = {
           isChecked: false
         };
6. Attach the **_buttonClicked** event handler to your button's **onClick** event:

   > <DefaultButton
   >   text="Button"
   >   **onClick={this._buttonClicked}**
   >   />
7. This should be it. Note that I force the checkbox to true when the button is clicked, but you could toggle is as well:

   ```
   private _buttonClicked(): void {
     this.setState({ **isChecked: this.state.isChecked!});**
   }
   ```

I hope this helps?!